# How to disable 'switch to Tab' feature in FireFox 4.0?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox 4, turn off “switch to tab” in URL bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/223584/firefox-4-turn-off-switch-to-tab-in-url-bar)

When I type a URL in the address bar, if the same url is opened in another tab, instead of auto-fill option it prompt only for switching to that tab. Is there any way to disable this feature? 
Note: this looks like a new feature in Firefox 4.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Start Firefox with all add-ons disabled or create a new profile by running it with the `-ProfileManager` switch to see if one of your add-ons is responsible.

Answer (score 2):

Install the add-on "switch-to-tab Blacklist" it will take care of this problem. Since the add-on at the moment seems to be for advanced users, according to the developer, you should know what you are doing. The extension lacks GUI.

Read the instructions on the add-on website to configure it: [switch-to-tab Blacklist](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-to-tab-blacklist/)

Set the about:config key *extension.switchToTabBlacklist.blacklist* to [".*"] if you want to blacklist all sites from the feature.

Comment: Realized that this question was already answered here at Superuser. Look at: http://superuser.com/questions/223584/firefox-4-turn-off-switch-to-tab-in-url-bar