# Preventing Firefox from replacing "open URL" with "Switch to tab"

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

How can I prevent Firefox from displaying "Switch to tab" under my address bar when I enter a URL I have open in another tab?

For example, say I have one jsbeautifier open, and I want to open another. When I start typing the URL, Firefox's only option is the "Switch to tab" command. I've tried using [filters](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Location%20bar%20autocomplete#w_changing-results-on-the-fly) with no result.

[image: Firefox suggests only "Switch to tab" command]

How do I make Firefox prompt to open new instance of that page as well?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks!

You should select _Switch to tab_ option with arrows, hit _Shift_. This will turn of "Switch to tab" thingy.Than you can hit _Enter_.

Answer (score 5):

I use the [Switch To Tab No More](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-to-tab-no-more/) add-on. It removes the "Switch to tab" option entirely, so you don't have to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> every time you try to double-open something.

(That said, I probably would have never installed it if I had known about the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> command Oliver suggested.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> at the front (or edit the url in any way and then undo).

Then the `switch to tab` disappears.